# How to set SeekBar progress with a long integer? (or alternatives)

Tags: java, android, integer, long-integer, seekbar

I need some help with an Android app. I want to use SeekBars to set a certain value but the value should be able to be a long (because I need such high numbers). Are there good custom SeekBars to import? (GitHub link would be great)

The normal SeekBar only supports normal integers as far as I know and casting to int is no option.

Comment: With the screen width as a limit to the seekbar length - how would I as a user manage to find a specific position if there are much less pixels to display the SeekBar than there are possible values?

Comment: If you would increase the value per pixel jumped. So for example you move the SeekBar 1 pixel and the value would change by 100.

Comment: you can divide value by a const and cast to an integer and for display it multiplied by const

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead use percentage formula.

- Set max of SeekBar to 100,
- Current position equals `(int)current_long/total_long * 100`

Comment: that doesn't work fine, as percentage is in integer.

Comment: it does work fine as value is being casted as integer, if you have doubts about casts you can Integer.parseInt(current_long/total_long * 100) @jairhumberto

Comment: It's not a matter of casting, it's the fact that the range from 0 to 100 should be double to accurately treat cases involving long. Ex. a hash table from 0 to 132150. If I drag the bar to 66% it will be 87219, if I drag to 67% it will be 88540... then what happens with in-between values, like 88000? There is no way to represent them. If 88000 comes from the database, using your formula, it would fall back to 87219, since there is a cast to int, so there is no way to accurately represent 88000, for example. The guy needs long values, he said: "casting to int is no option". Got it? @user10844401

Comment: Yes, the main problem is that the Seekbar, apparently, doesn't allow you to set a value greater than 100 for max. But if the progress was double, it would be no problem. It's a very inconvenient limitation.